# foreach возврощает всегда первую линию

Tags: php, массивы, функции, foreach

Начал писать собственный template class для своего сайта, весь класс работает, теперь начал писать вывод массива в шаблон и тут мне возвращает правильное количество линий только проблема в том что каждая линия в шаблон равно первой линии в цикле, как можно исправить ?

array

```
$allpm[] = array('id'=> '11', 'string'=> 'text 1');
$allpm[] = array('id'=> '22', 'string'=> 'text 2');
$allpm[] = array('id'=> '33', 'string'=> 'text 3');
```

функция что перерабатывает цикл (через print_r показывает все 3 линии правильно)

```
if (stristr($this->template, "{loop item=")) {
    preg_match('/{loop item=([a-z]+)\}(.*?){\/loop}/s', $this->template, $loopvar);
    if (count($this->loop_data[$loopvar[1]])) { 
        $loop_content = '';
         foreach ($this->loop_data[$loopvar[1]] as $main_loop) {
            foreach($main_loop as $key_find => $key_replace) {
                $find_item[] = '/{'.$key_find.'}/';
                $replace_item[] = $key_replace;

            }
            $loop_content .= preg_replace($find_item,$replace_item, $loopvar[2]);
         }
        $result = preg_replace( "/{loop item=([a-z]+)\}(.*?){\/loop}/s",$loop_content, $result); 
    }
}
```

в шаблоне так

```
{loop item=allpm}
id:{id}, string: {string}<br>
{/loop}
```

но на выходе всегда выходит

```
id:11, string: text 1
id:11, string: text 1
id:11, string: text 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас накапливаются элементы в массивах $find_item и $replace_item.

```
var_dump($find_item);
var_dump($replace_item);
```

Если добавить эти две строчки после внутреннего цикла, будет такой вывод:

После первого прохода:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "/{id}/"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "/{string}/"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "11"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "text 1"
}
```

После второго прохода:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "/{id}/"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "/{string}/"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "/{id}/"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "/{string}/"
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "11"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "text 1"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "22"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "text 2"
}
```

Добавьте код, инициализирующий эти массивы перед внутренним циклом, и проблема уйдет.

```
$find_item = array();
$replace_item = array();
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, сработало на ура